# Student Showdown - Q and A battle game, part 1: The Champions

Tags: java, javafx, battle-simulation

Just a self challenge/fun thing.

I have a scene where the player picks a character, of course it works but I'm repeating myself an awful lot. I would appreciate any formatting suggestions and making it more streamlined in general.

```
        Champion ranger = new Champion.Generator(
            "Legolas' Lover", // name
            new Image("/Resources/Ranger.gif"), // icon
            new Image("/Resources/Ranger.jpg")) // portrait
            .attack(4)
            .armor(2)
            .health(8)
            .description("Has less health than most, but decent armor, and strong attacks!")
        .generate();

        Champion dragon = new Champion.Generator(
            "Scion of Daenerys", // name
            new Image("/Resources/Dragon.gif"), // icon
            new Image("/Resources/Dragon.jpg")) // portrait
            .attack(4)
            .armor(2)
            .health(8)
            .description("Is a motherloving dragon")
        .generate();

        Champion angel = new Champion.Generator(
            "Full Metal Bitch", // name
            new Image("/Resources/Angel.gif"), // icon
            new Image("/Resources/Angel.jpg")) // portrait
            .attack(4)
            .armor(2)
            .health(8)
            .description("Really likes rock music, tons of defense")
        .generate();

        Champion spirit = new Champion.Generator(
            "Forlorn Phantasm", // name
            new Image("/Resources/Spirit.gif"), // icon
            new Image("/Resources/Spirit.jpg")) // portrait
            .attack(4)
            .armor(2)
            .health(8)
            .description("So much health, find yourself spirited away~")
        .generate();

        Champion knight = new Champion.Generator(
            "Dark Lancelot", // name
            new Image("/Resources/Knight.gif"), // icon
            new Image("/Resources/Knight.jpg")) // portrait
            .attack(4)
            .armor(2)
            .health(8)
            .description("He's flipping round tables!")
        .generate();

        Button rangerButton = new Button("Choose the Ranger.", new ImageView(ranger.portrait()));
        rangerButton.setTooltip(new Tooltip(ranger.description()));
        rangerButton.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TOP);

        Button dragonButton = new Button("Choose the Knight.", new ImageView(dragon.portrait()));
        dragonButton.setTooltip(new Tooltip(dragon.description()));
        dragonButton.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TOP);

        Button angelButton = new Button("Choose the Angel.", new ImageView(angel.portrait()));
        angelButton.setTooltip(new Tooltip(angel.description()));
        angelButton.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TOP);

        Button spiritButton = new Button("Choose the Spirit.", new ImageView(spirit.portrait()));
        spiritButton.setTooltip(new Tooltip(spirit.description()));
        spiritButton.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TOP);

        Button knightButton = new Button("Choose the Knight.", new ImageView(knight.portrait()));
        knightButton.setTooltip(new Tooltip(knight.description()));
        knightButton.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TOP);

        VBox rangerLayout = new VBox(10);
        rangerLayout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        rangerLayout.getChildren().add(rangerButton);

        VBox dragonLayout = new VBox(10);
        dragonLayout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        dragonLayout.getChildren().add(dragonLayout);

        VBox angelLayout = new VBox(10);
        angelLayout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        angelLayout.getChildren().add(angelLayout);

        VBox spiritLayout = new VBox(10);
        spiritLayout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        spiritLayout.getChildren().add(spiritButton);

        VBox knightLayout = new VBox(10);
        knightLayout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        knightLayout.getChildren().add(knightButton);

        HBox mainLayout = new HBox();
        mainLayout.getChildren().addAll(
            rangerLayout,
            dragonLayout,
            angelLayout,
            spiritLayout,
            knightLayout
        );

        stage.setScene(new Scene(mainLayout));
        stage.show();
```

In case it helps, the Champion class:

```
public class Champion {
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private Image icon;
    private Image portrait;
    private int armor;
    private int attack;
    private int health;
    private int maxHealth;

    public Image portrait() {
        return portrait;
    }

    public Image icon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public String name() {
        return name;
    }

    public String description() {
        return description;
    }

    Champion(Generator generator) {
        name = generator.name;
        description = generator.description;
        portrait = generator.portrait;
        icon = generator.icon;
        attack = generator.attack;
        armor = generator.armor;
        health = generator.health;
        maxHealth = generator.health;
    }

    static class Generator {
        String name;
        String description = "Please add a description for me Legato!";
        Image icon;
        Image portrait;
        int attack = 4;
        int armor = 0;
        int health = 15;

        Generator(String name, Image icon, Image portrait){
            this.name = name;
            this.icon = icon;
            this.portrait = portrait;
        }

        public Generator attack(int val){ attack = val;return this; }
        public Generator armor(int val){ armor = val; return this; }
        public Generator health(int val){ health = val; return this; }
        public Generator description(String text) { description = text; return this; }

        public Champion generate(){ return new Champion(this); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a couple of functions to avoid duplications. You already abstracted a lot away by introducing the `Champion` class, so this is actually rather easy:

```
private Button getButton(Champion champion, String name) {
   Button button = new Button("Choose the " + name + ".", new ImageView(champion.portrait()));
    button.setTooltip(new Tooltip(champion.description()));
    button.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TOP);
    return button;
}

private VBox getBox(Button button) {
    VBox layout = new VBox(10);
    layout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    layout.getChildren().add(button);
    return layout;
}
```

If you add the name string to the `Champion` class, you wouldn't need to pass it to the method.

Then use it like this:

```
    HBox mainLayout = new HBox();
    mainLayout.getChildren().addAll(
        getBox(getButton(ranger, "Ranger")),
        [...]
    );
```

Answer (score 10):

**A List, a list! My kingdom for a list!**

```
List<Champion> champions = new ArrayList<>();
champions.add(new Champion.Generator(
        "Legolas' Lover", // name
        new Image("/Resources/Ranger.gif"), // icon
        new Image("/Resources/Ranger.jpg")) // portrait
        .attack(4)
        .armor(2)
        .health(8)
        .description("Has less health than most, but decent armor, and strong attacks!")
    .generate());
...
```

- Add all champions to a list
- Loop through the list of champions and for each champion:

  - Create the button
  - Create the `VBox`
  - Add the `VBox` to the main layout

#### Additional observations

Currently all your champions are hard-coded into the code. I can highly recommend *loading the champion data from a file*.

Additionally, your 'icon' and 'portrait' are very similar, perhaps it is enough to specify `"Ranger"` instead of `"/Resources/Ranger.gif"` and `"/Resources/Ranger.jpg"` ?

In your code it seems to be "obvious" that a .gif is icon and .jpg is portrait. I would recommend naming them `ranger_icon.gif` and `ranger_portrait.jpg` instead though.

Answer (score 7):

As already said, a kingdom for a list and small one for a CSV:

```
IconName;Name;Attack;Armor;Health;Description
Ranger;Legolas' Lover;4;2;8;Has less health than most, but decent armor, and strong attacks!
Dragon;Scion of Daenerys;4;2;8;Is a motherloving dragon
Angel;Full Metal Bitch;4;2;8;Really likes rock music, tons of defense
Spirit;Forlorn Phantasm;4;2;8;So much health, find yourself spirited away~
Champion;Dark Lancelot;4;2;8;He's flipping round tables!
```

Just get a CSV-library or write a simple parser yourself. This trivial table contains all the information from your first 50 lines. It also makes obvious, that there's something wrong with your Attack/Armor/Health, which is harder to spot in the code.

---

This is a rather hacky way how you could parse a CSV line yourself.

```
@Getter
public class Champion {
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private Image icon;
    private Image portrait;
    private int armor;
    private int attack;
    private int health;
    private int maxHealth;

    // This is pretty hacky, but very simple if you want no CSV library.
    // You wan't be able to use semicolons in the text, but do you care?
    private Champion(String csvLine) {
        // A better version of String.split
        List<String> split = Splitter.on(';')
             .omitEmpty().splitToList(csvLine);
        // It's not a good style to use magic constants in code,
        // but I'm too lazy now.
        Preconditions.checkArgument(split.size() == 6);
        String iconName = split[0];
        icon = new Image("Resources/" + iconName + ".gif");
        portrait = new Image("Resources/" + iconName + ".jpg");
        name = split[1];
        attack = Integer.parseInt(split[2]);
        armor = Integer.parseInt(split[3]);
        health = Integer.parseInt(split[4]);
        description = split[5];
        name = name;
    }
}
```

The [Splitter](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) and [Preconditions](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html) classes are part of Guava. [@Getter](http://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter.html) comes from project Lombok. There's also a `@Builder` there, which creates a class working just like your `Generator` ("Builder" is the right name here).

Answer (score 5):

#### The builder pattern

Your `Generator` class implements the builder pattern.
The common vocabulary for the pattern is `Builder` for the class and `builder` for the method.
Not only that, the term "generator" is misleading,
as in many languages it means a special [iterator-like construct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_(computer_programming)).
It's actually an extremely practical thing and my eyes always light up whenever I see "generator".
In this program however you have "just a builder",
so I suggest to call it that way.

You're not using the pattern to its full potential.
For example you could make the fields of Champion `final`.

When using the builder pattern,
it's a common practice (but not at all mandatory)
to prevent constructing the class directly by making its constructor `private`.
The benefit of doing so is to limit the choices of the programmer,
thereby making execution more straightforward.
For example one might question if they should create a `Champion` using the builder, or using `Champion(builder)`.
Which is non-sense, of course they should use the builder,
so make that loud and clear by making that the *only way*.

Lastly,
I'd add a `shortName` field to make the button creation easier.
In the current code you hardcoded texts like "Choose the Dragon.",
which can become `String.format("Choose the %s.", champ.shortName)`.

#### Question the comments

When you find yourself adding comments like this:

> ```
> new Image("/Resources/Dragon.gif"), // icon
> new Image("/Resources/Dragon.jpg")) // portrait
> ```

Ask yourself if the code can be written to make this obvious.

In this program for example you could add the builder methods `icon(...)` and `portrait(...)`.

Comment: Janos. :D :D :D :D

I've missed seeing you around! Thank you as usual for the great answer.